# Could not find any GraphQL schema file under configured locations - SpringBoot , GraphQL

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I'm trying to run empty project on spring-boot with GraphQL, but I'm getting following error.

```
2022-01-03 12:33:11.440 ERROR 12944 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Could not find any GraphQL schema file under configured locations.

Action:

Check that the following locations contain schema files: 
- '' (classpath:graphql/**/)
```

Dependencies:

- spring-boot-starter-graphql
- spring-boot-starter-web

Scheme - `/resources/schema.graphqls` :

```
type Query {
  bookById(id: ID): Book
}

type Book {
  id: ID
  name: String
  pageCount: Int
  author: Author
}

type Author {
  id: ID
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
}
```

Is there any configuration error?

Comment: The error message tells you Spring GraphQL looks for the schema files in the class path under the `graphql/` directory. Move your schema files to the `src/main/resources/graphql/` directory.

Comment: The selected answer works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rename your file to schema.graphql file to schema.graphqls

Answer (score 0):

looks like you should change location path to

```
classpath:/**/
```

Comment: hey, can you add some information about why this issue occurred, and why your change fixes it?

Comment: It's depends where your schema is. By the way, to understand which is the right value, you can add brakepoint in configuration class

Comment: I don't think so, the change does nothing.